# How can I output a string from an array of characters with a space as a delimiter?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I don't konw I can i add space between the char print out
below is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Slide{
    private char[][] cells;

    public Slide(){
        cells= new char[][]{//
            {'@','@','@','@'},
            {'@','@','@','@'},
            {'@','@','@','@'},
            {'@','@','@','@'}
        }; 

    }

    public Slide(char[][] cells){// 
        for(int row=0; row<cells.length; row++)
            for(int column = 0; column<cells[row].length; column++)

                this.cells = cells;
    }

    public void print(){

        for(char[] a: cells){
            System.out.println(a);//



        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Asking a question requires some basic knowledge of the problem at hand, you should check out the java documentation for string and array manipulation > http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html -- which are some fundamental principles of java. (hint:use concatenation)

Comment: I don't understand the question, where do you want to put the spaces?, you could do System.out.print(a+" "); instead of System.out.println(a);

Answer (score 3):

Printing an array directly is generally not what you want to do since arrays don't override `toString`, meaning the output will not be meaningful in most contexts. If all you're interested in is printing with spaces between elements, then this should suffice:

```
for (char[] a : cells) {
    for (char c : a) {
        System.out.print(c);
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

By the way, I have no idea what you're doing (or trying to do) in the second `Slide` constructor. You're just assigning `this.cells` to `cells` a bunch of times. Did you mean to make a copy of `cells`?

```
this.cells = new char[cells.length][];  // create new empty array

for(int row = 0; row < cells.length; row++) {
    this.cells[row] = new char[cells[row].length];  // initialize row

    for(int column = 0; column < cells[row].length; column++)
        this.cells[row][column] = cells[row][column];  // copy elements
}
```